# what's the difference between Array and Buffer when using scala?

Tags: scala

when I work on some task using scala , I wrote some code as follows:

```
object He {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var myMatrix = Array.ofDim[String](3,3)
    // build a matrix
    for (i <- 0 to 1) {
      for ( j <- 0 to 1) {
        myMatrix(i)(j) = "faf";
      }
    }
    var eventbuffer = for(i <- myMatrix) yield for(j <- i) yield j
    var eventArray =  for(i <- eventbuffer) yield i.toArray
    var eventpool:Array[(String, Array[String])] =   eventArray.toArray.map(son => (son(0), son))
  }
}
```

I want to ask the question ，what's the differece between the eventbuffer and eventArray?Last,what will the eventpool be like? I am really confused,Thank for
helping me for that

Answer (score 8):

In Scala an `Array` is just a JVM Array, while the various `Buffer`s are actual classes.

An `Array[String]` ist the same as a `String[]` in Java.
You can think of an `ArrayBuffer` as an `ArrayList` in Java (they're very similar, but not equivalent) and of the `ListBuffer` as a Java `LinkedList` (again, similar, but not the same).

One should note however, that in your example `eventbuffer` is not a `Buffer`, but an Array of Arrays. In fact it is pretty much an exact copy of `myMatrix`, so the call to the `toArray` method is actually redundant.

Comment: Are you mean that the `var eventpool:Array[(String, Array[String])] = myMatrix.map(son => (son(0), son))` is equal to `var eventpool:Array[(String, Array[String])] =   eventArray.toArray.map(son => (son(0), son))`?

Comment: It should be, yeah :)